# After upgrading to Windows 10 from 7 my User is no longer being counted as an Administrator when running certain programs

Tags: permissions, windows-10, administrator, windows-10-upgrade, visual-studio-2013

My user account is still an Administrator.

Visual Studio 2013, wouldn't let me attach to process. Says it needs to restart as administrator. This was not an issue with Windows 7 only started after upgrading to Windows 10.

Also seemed like the same user lost Administrative access over Report Server 2012. I am now getting permission errors when my application attempts to call it via HTTP when running under my same user account in IIS. This also worked previously without issue.

Is something different in the way Windows 10 runs programs that would be causing this? All I did was upgrade, the dev environment worked fine previously in Windows 7.

Comment: Did you disable UAC in 7?

Comment: @ScottChamberlain Yes. I am actually trying to re-enable it right now and see what happens...

Answer (score 0):

Windows 10 has a setting to not ask for administration rights in general.

Another simple solution would be to strip that account of it's admin rights sign in and off as normal user and give the admin rights back to that user. This worked at least once.

Comment: *"Windows 10 has a setting to not ask for administration rights in general."* -- if that means it will get administrative rights without asking, then that sounds like a thing you should not enable...?

Comment: It does not ask for at least some applications, so yes it is a very stupid feature but changing, rebooting and changing them back works remarkably often in windows...